# Temperature Converter with GUI issues

Tags: python, tkinter, series

This is a temperature converter with a GUI. I am having issues with the GUI aspect. My code ran correctly before I added in the GUI, and now says its all checked out but nothing will happen when I actually run the program. I don't know if it's because I need the Tkinter file to be in the same folder possibly? I had that issue when getting text from a file earlier or if my GUI is just completely programmed incorrectly! Thanks!

```
#import
#main function
from Tkinter import *
def main():
    root=Tk()

    root.title("Temperature Converter")
    root.geometry("400x700")
    #someothersting=""
    someotherstring=""
#enter Celcius
    L1=Label(root,text="Enter a Celcius temperature.")
    E1=Entry(root,textvariable=someotherstring)
    somebutton=Button(root, text="Total", command=lambda: convert(E1.get()))

    somebutton.pack()
    E1.pack()
    L1.pack()
    root.mainloop()#main loop


#convert Celcius to Fahrenheit
def convert(somestring):
    if somestring != "":    
        # cel=0 dont need these in python
        # far=0
        cel=int(somestring)
        far=(9/5*(cel))+32
        print(F)
```

Comment: It is in python 2 as well

Comment: Lots of languages will call `main` for you automatically, but Python is not one of them. Try adding `main()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

add main() and change F to far.  I also added in an example to make the label state what the conversion is!:) Hope this helps.

```
#import
#main function
from Tkinter import *
def main():
    root=Tk()

    root.title("Temperature Converter")
    root.geometry("400x700")
    #someothersting=""
    someotherstring=""
#enter Celcius
    L1=Label(root,text="Enter a Celcius temperature.")
    E1=Entry(root,textvariable=someotherstring)
    somebutton=Button(root, text="Total", command=lambda: convert(E1.get()))

    somebutton.pack()
    E1.pack()
    L1.pack()
    root.mainloop()#main loop


#convert Celcius to Fahrenheit
def convert(somestring, label):
    if somestring != "":
        cel=int(somestring)
        far=(9/5*(cel))+32
        answer = str(cel) + " Converted to Farenheit = " + str(far)
        label.config(text=answer)

main()
```